# Fastest Image delivery from local server or CDN, or Cloud?

Tags: image, cloud, local-storage, cdn

My situation is as follows. I've a reasonably fast website that hosts around 200,000 images. I'm as of now using these images without any problem  (reasonably fast image loading) and displaying it on my website. But now, I realise that I have an option to download all these 200,000 onto my local server using a small python script. I could also upload these 200,000 images onto a cloud, CDN.

I've seen famous websites like google request their data from a separate domain and most probably a separate server.

So my question is this. Which is the best way to store a large number of image files for fastest delivery on my webpage. Is it on a local server, a external server or a strategically placed server like what CDNs do? Because, I'm under the impression right now that data is transfer ed within the server fastest and hence it would be best to have it on my local server.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "within the server fastest"? If you're only worried about transferring within your  own system, then certainly having it local is best. But it seems like you're asking about what would be best for external users of the site.

Comment: I'm sorry. What I meant is  I would be displaying the images on my webpage (saY). In which case, would a local server be betteR?

Comment: Remember your end users are requesting each resource separately, so for them "local" would (generally) be closer to their physical location, not your server.

Comment: @JoshuaDeWald Yes I do get that. But my point being that the data is sent fro my server which is less strained in terms of bandwidth instead of a cdn perhaps? I dont have that many visitors.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of visitors, it's likely not worth it (integration points, etc). In terms of a bandwidth, a CDN shouldn't be strained under most normal circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

The term fastest depends on so many factors like

1. Region of server located
2. Bandwidth of server and user
3. Server RAM Size & Hard Disk read/write speed

When having same features comparing to cloud,cdn,local 
I choose cloud because reliability of cloud is better than local

Comment: "reliability of cloud is better" - This statement is way to generic. If I look to uptimes of CDNs, it's about 99 %. The uptime of my server is 99.99 %.